# Visual Studio project to call Azure ML Endpoint, namespace how-to

Tags: visual-studio-code, webforms, namespaces, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a Visual Studio WebForm C# project that loads in a browser. I also have a snippet of code from Azure ML to call my endpoint model. How should the *.aspx.cs file look? Thank you.
[screen shot of my visual studio *.aspx.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGogg.png)

Here is how I plan to call it from the carprice.aspx file:

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblResults" runat="server" Text="here is where results will go"></asp:Label>
```

Here is the Namespace template from Visual Studio project, the carprice.aspx.cs file:

```
namespace web13
{
public partial class carprice : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

And here is the snippet from Azure, a different kind of namespace syntax:

```
namespace CallRequestResponseService
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait();
    }

    static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => { return true; }
        };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            // Request data goes here
            var scoreRequest = new
            {
                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>()
                {
                    {
                        "input1",
                        new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
                        {
                            new Dictionary<string, string>()
                            {
                                {
                                    "price", "5800"
                                },
                                {
                                    "year", "2013"......etc
```

The next day, I tried calling HTML label control from the Azure snippet of code, but I get an error, "the name lblResults2 does not exist in the current context." I've also tried changing the Azure snippet to Public classes. Here is another screen shot. thank you.
[Visual Studio connecting Azure Results to form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzfSZ.png)

Then further along, I'm adding newer screen shots
[Visual Studio webform controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqjrd.png)
[Visual Studio namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th5Xw.png)

further days along, this is what gets Visual Studio to compile and load in browser. screen shot is:
[working syntax for calling endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP2O3.png)

Comment: I've tried changing the code-behind for the form Submit/Predict-Button to "async Task" and then I modified the static data to form controls, "price", "5800" changes to "price", txtprice.Text, and  "year", rblyear.SelectedItem.Text for example. But I get the error for each form item, CS0120, An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'.

Comment: OK, it's working by changing the static and Task to public and void, for button click event handler. And I do not need this namespace provided by Azure Consume snippet. And the change to Public allowed intellisense to work. However, Not sure if this is proper to change the code that Azure endpoint Consume TAB generated for me(?). No more Visual Studio compile errors. It's only failing because the Azure ML endpoint is not running, here is the line of code that makes a request to the Azure ML endpoint, HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("", content);